# I only want to select date from these columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I only want to select date 170522 yymmdd from these rows.

```
PRD.SBR.BATCH.D170522.T011726.
```

Comment: Row  or column ??  is a single string value in a column?

Comment: coumn name is source_file_name i only need date from this col not other values

Comment: then date is always alfter the   `.D`  string?

Comment: What can be the different formats of your file string? Is it always fixed length, is the date always the 4th part, does the date always follows .D?

Comment: yes its always the 4th part. so i just want to select this date from this column

Comment: select B.SOURCE_FILE_NAME A.* from STG0_HST_SBR_AIR_SEG A, SBR_SRC_HEADER B
WHERE A.SBR_ID=B.SBR_ID

Comment: here is my query but when i select source_file_name its give me a complete result but i only want to select date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle you can use something like below, this will give you the 4th part of your file name string:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(FILE_NAME_FIELD, INSTR(FILE_NAME_FIELD, '.', 0, 3) + 1, 7) FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```

The INSTR inner function will find the index of the 4th occurrence of the dot, and the SUBSTR will take the substring as of that index with a fixed length of 7 (the length of the date part).

The result from your sample data would be:

> D170522

You can still format this any way you like, eg strip the D and cast it to an actual date...

Comment: SUBSTRING_INDEX IS INVALID IDENTIFIER, ORACLE ERROR.

Comment: You wrongly flagged the question as mysql, so my answer is based on that. I'll check for an Oracle equivalent.

Comment: I've adjusted my answer for Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

If the string always looks like this, and as you tagged the question with the Oracle tag, then

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'PRD.SBR.BATCH.D170522.T011726.' from dual)
  3  select regexp_substr(col, '\d+') result
  4  from test;

RESULT
------
170522

SQL>
```

which says: give me the first "number" from the input string.